# Flutter SharedPreferences from a static method of a class return null

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am trying to make an HTTP request from a static method of dart class from my main screen
this static method retrieves a variable stored in SharedPreferences and sends it with the HTTP request as a parameter but the value of this shredPref is always null or empty because the HTTP request is sent before I get the SharedPreferences value.
How to get the value before making the HTTP request?
here is my code:

call the method from the main screen when the button is clicked

```
      onPressed: () {
        if(isUserLoggedIn){
          MyHelper.toggleFavoritesProperty(context, property.property_id);
        }else{
          //show alert to user to login
        }
      },
```

and this is MyHelper class:

```
class MyHelper {
 static Future<String> getSharedPreferencesString(String key) async {
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String storedValue = preferences.getString(key);
    return storedValue;
  }

  static Future<bool> toggleFavoritesProperty(BuildContext context, String propertyID) async{
    MyHelper.progressDialogIndicatorOnly(true, context);
    String url = "https://www.apps.com/services/";
    var myData = {
      'post_id': propertyID,
      'user_id': await getSharedPreferencesString("user_id") ,
      'user_token': await getSharedPreferencesString("user_token") ,
      'rand':MyHelper.generateRandomNumberForURL()
    };

    var params = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    params['action'] = 'toggle_favorites';
    params['data'] = json.encode(myData);
    print(params);

    Response response = await post(url, body: params);
    Navigator.pop(context);
    print(response.body);
    if(response.statusCode == 200){
      var jsonData = json.decode(response.body);
      print(jsonData);
      if(jsonData["success"] == true){
        // everything is ok
      }else {
// validate failed
      }
    }else{
      //Navigator.pop(context);
      throw Exception("We can not finish your request!!!!");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: 1. Is the value present in shared preferences in the first place? 2. Don't know if it helps, but can you try assigning the two getters to respective variables and then using those variables to assign `myData`?

Comment: I already did this and got the same result

Comment: If you remove the POST request and just await on the sharedpreference values, are you getting them?

Comment: Thanks a lot, fixed it after removing the POST request there was a spelling mistake everything worked after correcting the mistake

Answer (score 1):

There was a spelling mistake, everything worked fine once I fixed it

```
'user_token': await getSharedPreferencesString("user_token") ,
```

TO

```
'user_token': await getSharedPreferencesString("stored_user_token") ,
```

The key was wrong